# Adding live update values into Callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js, auto-update

I'm trying to make a live update chart, I could manage to get live update values into the Data and the label part, but I can't seem to make it work for the callback. I have 5 arrays from a separate file with stores 5 different data, the fifth array is the one I need to add into my CallBack part, The values from that array would need to go into another array, so I can use into my function, or just make a path to the callbacks part and add the values there. For the ones I could manage doing the live update, I just made a path to the function. 
Chart:

```
 function loadData() {
      $.getJSON('loadchart.php', function(response) {
        myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data = response[0];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[1].data = response[1];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[2].data = response[2];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[3].data = response[3];
        myLineChart.data.labels = response[4];

        myLineChart.update();
      });
    }

    loadData();
    setInterval(loadData, 5000);

    var lbl = [];
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychart1').getContext('2d');

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line', 
        data: {
          labels: lbl,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Corrente 1",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'red',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 2",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'blue',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 3",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'green',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente Total",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'black',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
          ]            
        },
        options: {
          animation:{
            update: 0
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 20,
            text: "Gráfico das Correntes"
          },

          labels: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
          },

          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            responsive: true,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            titleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
            titleFontSize: 14,
            titleFontStyle: 'bold',
            titleAlign: 'center',
            titleSpacing: 4,
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            bodyFontFamily: "'Mukta'",
            bodyFontSize: 14,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            callbacks:{
              title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
              },
              afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var tempo = [];
                return tempo[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
              },
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                    return label;
              }
            }
          },
          aspectRatio: 1,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });
```

This is the part I would need to add the fifht array:

```
afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var tempo = [];
                return tempo[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
              },
```

Comment: add live demo for ur snippet

Comment: @sonnenhaft what is that, and how can i do it?